# npm Node.js Error: No native build was found M2 MacBook

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I got this error on my M2 MacBook, running a project, that worked on my old Intel MacBook. Do you have any idea what the problem is?

I am using [bun](https://bun.sh) but `npm run dev` (node 18) gives me the same error.

The exact same error occurred on other projects.

Package.json dependencies:

```json
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/three": "^0.143.1",
  "parcel": "^2.7.0"
},
"dependencies": {
  "three": "^0.143.0"
}
```

Console output for `bun run dev`:

```
$ parcel src/index.html --open
Error: No native build was found for platform=darwin arch=x64 runtime=node abi=108 uv=1 libc=glibc node=18.7.0
    loaded from: /Users/frankmayer/Documents/Git/WorldArchitect/WebGLPreview/node_modules/lmdb and package: @lmdb/lmdb-darwin-x64

    at load.path (/Users/frankmayer/Documents/Git/WorldArchitect/WebGLPreview/node_modules/node-gyp-build-optional-packages/index.js:64:9)
    at Object.load [as default] (/Users/frankmayer/Documents/Git/WorldArchitect/WebGLPreview/node_modules/node-gyp-build-optional-packages/index.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/frankmayer/Documents/Git/WorldArchitect/WebGLPreview/node_modules/lmdb/dist/index.cjs:47:47)
    at Module._compile (/Users/frankmayer/Documents/Git/WorldArchitect/WebGLPreview/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1174:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:19)
    at require (/Users/frankmayer/Documents/Git/WorldArchitect/WebGLPreview/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at _lmdb (/Users/frankmayer/Documents/Git/WorldArchitect/WebGLPreview/node_modules/@parcel/cache/lib/LMDBCache.js:61:39)
Script error "dev" exited with 1 status
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override a version using the override option in you `package.json`.

Read more about this option here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides

For me, the solution was to add this to my `package.json`:

```json
"overrides": {
  "lmdb": "2.6.0-alpha6",
  "@lmdb/lmdb-darwin-arm64": "2.6.0-alpha6",
  "@lmdb/lmdb-darwin-x64": "2.6.0-alpha6",
}
```

This feature is currently (Aug. 2022) not supported by bun!

Yarn does this using resolutions: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions